# What is the effect of typedef'ing a struct to itself?

Tags: c++, c, struct

I've seen this code written at the top of an API:

```
typedef struct SYSTEM SYSTEM;
```

The type `SYSTEM` was previously undefined. Does anyone know what this does? What does the compiler think a `SYSTEM` after this line?

Thanks for the answers! My question is that SYSTEM was not previously defined in the file, so I have no idea what it is. For example, that line will compile by itself, but `struct SYSTEM` was not defined anywhere.

Comment: You tagged this both `c` and `c++`. Which one of these two languages are you talking about?

Comment: There's an excellent answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c

Comment: It's a C API, but also works with a C++ compiler.

Comment: Are you talking about `struct SYSTEM` specifically or generically?  Is `SYSTEM` just an example or are you trying to determine what that particular struct is for?

Comment: Thanks, I mean that 'struct SYSTEM' has not been defined anywhere before that line of code. So it compiles, but I have no idea what a SYSTEM (or struct SYSTEM) actually is :)

Comment: @James: If `struct SYSTEM` is really not defined before this point (not even in a header that you include directly or indirectly,) then this line serves as a sort of a forward declaration. From this point on, `SYSTEM` will be an *incomplete type*, which means you can only declare pointers to it (and a couple of other things,) but you cannot have variables of this type until its fully defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It allows you in C to use the name `SYSTEM` instead of using `struct SYSTEM`.
The `typedef` creates a synonym `SYSTEM` to  `struct SYSTEM`.

In your case as `struct SYSTEM` is not declared, the declaration also declares `struct SYSTEM` as an incomplete type like in this declaration: `struct SYSTEM;`.

The complete object type `struct SYSTEM` can then be declared in another translation unit.

Comment: Thanks, as above - struct SYSTEM has not been defined anywhere.

Comment: @James: You just defined it -- as an incomplete type.

Comment: @James I added an edit to cover your comment.

Answer (score 4):

This is really only effective and useful in C.

In C, you have to type `struct type`, while C++ allows you to omit the `struct` part of the type and just write `type`.

`typedef struct type type` allows you to use `type` in C without having to use the `struct` keyword before the struct name.

Some C programmers regard this bad practice though, and prefer to write `struct type`. Just trying to put that out there.

---

The reason you're not getting any errors is because that line acts as a forward declaration for the `struct SYSTEM` that may or may not exist. All the `typedef` does is tell the compiler that when you say `X`, you mean `Y`.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is about how this line is valid before struct SYSTEM is defined anywhere?

Comment: @James I have updated my answer. Does that answer your question?