# What does this C code mean?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I know that typedef'ing allows you to refer to a struct without using the struct keyword. However, with this:

```
typedef struct SYSTEM SYSTEM;
```

I've seen this typedef in a `C` API, but `struct SYSTEM` has *not* been defined previously.

In fact, a `.c` file containing only that line will compile by itself.

What does the compiler think `SYSTEM (or struct SYSTEM)` actually is?

Many thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the effect of typedef'ing a struct to itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515787/what-is-the-effect-of-typedefing-a-struct-to-itself)

Comment: ***You asked this question 18 minutes ago.*** It has been closed. Why are you reposting it, seriously?

Comment: @H2CO3: it's because he updated the question later and nobody answered that question... the updated question isn't a duplicate, and it shouldn't have been closed. and because there's no answer there this one shouldn't be closed as a duplicate either. oh well, it's complicated.

Comment: @haccks one should take time before to vote for close question and down vote.

Comment: @Grijesh; I did't vote down bro....and also I have not yet gained privilege to close questions :)

Comment: @haccks I asked you so that you can support my comment ;) , sorry misinterpreted

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan; :D, very smart. Yes you are right, one should take time to down vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The struct doesn't need to be defined. It only needs to be *declared*. The typedef declaration you present subsumes the declaration of `struct SYSTEM`.

So it's equivalent to:

```
struct SYSTEM;

typedef struct SYSTEM SYSTEM;
```

Thanks to this typedef, `SYSTEM` now names an incomplete type, so you can use it like `SYSTEM *` in interface definitions, without needing to expose the actual definition of the struct, which can be kept private:

**public_header.h:**

```
typedef struct SYSTEM SYSTEM;

SYSTEM * create_system();

int do_useful_thing_with(SYSTEM * system, int count, void * addr);

void destroy_system(SYSTEM * system);
```

**private_impl.c:**

```
#include <public_header.h>

struct SYSTEM { int a; char b[12]; float q; void * next; };

SYSTEM * create_system()
{ 
    SYSTEM * p = malloc(sizeof *p);
    if (p) { p->a = 2; p->q = 1.5; }
    return p;
}

void destroy_system(SYSTEM * system)
{
    free(system);
}

// etc.
```

Comment: Thanks! So presumably the API programmers have defined this somewhere on the API-side of the interface?

Comment: @James: It's not empty. It's undefined. An empty struct is a defined struct like `struct Foo {};`. I added an explanation; you can use it as an incomplete type.

Comment: The purpose of being allowed to reference undefined structs is so that you can create pointers to that struct - perhaps from within that struct (this is most useful for declaring linked-lists, for example).

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical C construct, as opposed to C++ and Java etc, that directly define types in the global namespace. C structs cannot be accessed by their name only, so the `typedef` is needed to be able to call a SYSTEM just `SYSTEM`.

```
struct SYSTEM {
  ...
};
struct SYSTEM foo;   //legal
SYSTEM bar;   //illegal
typedef struct SYSTEM SYSTEM;   //give it a global name
SYSTEM baz;   //now it's legal
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd say this is generally ill-advised behaviour but the gist is:

```
typedef type name
```

..where here the *type* is `struct SYSTEM` and the name assigned is `SYSTEM`.

Usually one would give a different name to the typedef than the type the typedef is derived from. Hence the low opinion many code maintainers might have to this kind of behaviour.

Comment: It is good if you use it right, it is bad if you abuse it. Good usage is usually precisely what the OP asked about (getting rid of unnecessary `struct` clutter), bad usage is precisely what you are talking about (giving arbitrary names to stuff already named).

Comment: Calling `struct` "clutter" is a gross misunderstanding of the type system in C and/or pure laziness.

Comment: *Usually one would give a different name to the typedef than the type the typedef is derived from.*  Um, no.  `typedef struct NAME NAME` is an extremely common idiom in older C code.  It's DIY syntactic sugar to avoid having to type "struct" over and over.  Nothing wrong with it.